# table columns unfindable in query

Tags: sql-server

I'm using this query, but I get an error `vdagbk.bedrag` and `vdagbk.reden` .

Problem is, if I would put in in the second SELECT the result would certainly be wrong as it sums the result to many times due to double data in the table.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
   SUM(P.bedrag) AS ex, 
   C.dosno, 
   C.dosnm, 
   SUM(P.betaald) AS TotBetaald, 
   SUM(CASE vdagbk.reden WHEN 'H' THEN vdagbk.bedrag END)  AS Expr1
FROM         
   dbo.verkopen AS P 
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT DISTINCT 
         dbo.doss.dosno, dbo.doss.dosnm, dbo.verkopen.ino
    FROM dbo.verkopen 
    INNER JOIN dbo.doss ON dbo.verkopen.ino = dbo.doss.ino 
    INNER JOIN dbo.vdagbk ON dbo.verkopen.ino = dbo.vdagbk.ino
    WHERE      
        (dbo.doss.uitvoerder LIKE 'LL') 
        AND (dbo.doss.dosno LIKE '101520')
    GROUP BY 
        dbo.doss.dosno, dbo.doss.dosnm, dbo.verkopen.ino) AS C ON C.ino = P.ino 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.vdagbk AS vdagbk_1 ON P.ino = vdagbk_1.ino
GROUP BY 
    C.dosno, C.dosnm
```

How can I make this query work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're giving your table `dbo.vdagbk` an alias `vdagbk_1` here:

```
INNER JOIN
    dbo.vdagbk AS vdagbk_1 ON P.ino = vdagbk_1.ino
```

so you also need to use that **alias** in your `SUM()` clause here:

```
SUM(CASE vdagbk.reden WHEN 'H' THEN vdagbk.bedrag END)  AS Expr1
```

Change this to:

```
SUM(CASE vdagbk_1.reden WHEN 'H' THEN vdagbk_1.bedrag END)  AS Expr1
```

and it should work.